# Stream Future in Play 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework, streaming, akka, akka-stream

Once again I am attempting to update some pre Play 2.5 code (based on this [vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4b1XLka0UIw)). For example the following used to be how to stream a *Future*:

```
  Ok.chunked(Enumerator.generateM(Promise.timeout(Some("hello"), 500)))
```

I have created the following method for the work-around for `Promise.timeout` (deprecated) using *Akka*:

```
  private def keepResponding(data: String, delay: FiniteDuration, interval: FiniteDuration): Future[Result] = {
    val promise: Promise[Result] = Promise[Result]()
    actorSystem.scheduler.schedule(delay, interval) { promise.success(Ok(data)) }
    promise.future
  }
```

According to the [Play Framework Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/StreamsMigration25#Migrating-Enumerators-to-Sources); `Enumerators` should be *rewritten to a Source* and `Source.unfoldAsync` is apparently the equivalent of `Enumerator.generateM` so I was hoping that this would work (where `str` is a `Future[String]`):

```
  def inf = Action { request =>
    val str = keepResponding("stream me", 1.second, 2.second)

    Ok.chunked(Source.unfoldAsync(str))
  }
```

Of course I'm getting a *Type mismatch* error and when looking at the case class signature of `unfoldAsync`:

```
final class UnfoldAsync[S, E](s: S, f: S ⇒ Future[Option[(S, E)]])
```

I can see that the parameters are not correct but I'm not fully understanding what/how I should pass this through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unfoldAsync` is even more generic than Play!'s own `generateM`, as it allows you to pass through a status (`S`) value. This can make the value emitted depend on the previously emitted value(s).

The example below will load values by an increasing id, until the loading fails:

```
val source: Source[String, NotUsed] = Source.unfoldAsync(0){ id ⇒
  loadFromId(id)
    .map(s ⇒ Some((id + 1, s)))
    .recover{case _ ⇒ None}
}

def loadFromId(id: Int): Future[String] = ???
```

In your case an internal state is not really needed, therefore you can just pass dummy values whenever required, e.g.

```
val source: Source[Result, NotUsed] = Source.unfoldAsync(NotUsed) { _ ⇒
  schedule("stream me", 2.seconds).map(x ⇒ Some(NotUsed → x))
}

def schedule(data: String, delay: FiniteDuration): Future[Result] = {
  akka.pattern.after(delay, system.scheduler){Future.successful(Ok(data))}
}
```

Note that your original implementation of `keepResponding` is incorrect, as you cannot complete a `Promise` more than once. Akka `after` pattern offer a simpler way to achieve what you need.

However, note that in your specific case, Akka Streams offers a more idiomatic solution with `Source.tick`:

```
val source: Source[String, Cancellable] = Source.tick(1.second, 2.seconds, NotUsed).mapAsync(1){ _ ⇒
  loadSomeFuture()
}

def loadSomeFuture(): Future[String] = ???
```

or even simpler in case you don't actually need asynchronous computation as in your example

```
val source: Source[String, Cancellable] = Source.tick(1.second, 2.seconds, "stream me")
```

Comment: Thanks. Your 3rd & 4th example work but both of these take at least a few minutes to output the first result which feels like it shouldn't be happening. Any way to speed this up that you can think of? Also for some reason I couldn't get the first example working - an error of ***forward reference extends over definition of value source***. Thanks